# getting string from resource strings.xml

Tags: android

When I get the string from the `strings.xml` , I don't get an error right away, but I can't run the program :

```
String myButtonText = getString(R.string.ButtonText);
```

(when I remove this line and this variable from my program it works perfectly)

I'll put up my program, in case you'd need it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    String myButtonText = getString(R.string.ButtonText);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

           if(myButtonText.equals("Red")){//the button's text is "red" already
               button.setText("Blue");
           }
            }//I'm changing the text on the button to "blue" when it says"red"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the attribution from the top of the class and do this inside the onCreate method: `myButtonText = getResources().getString(R.string.ButtonText)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `getString(...)` within the activity lifecycle to ensure that all the components under the hood are initialized.

In your example, you should call `myButtonText = getString(R.string.ButtonText);` in `onCreate(...)`

Comment: Thank you that worked i did String myButtonText; then myButtonText in oncreat()

Answer (score 1):

You are doing:

```
String myButtonText = getString(R.string.ButtonText);
```

I think you have to retrieve value from `strings.xml` inside `onCreate()` method:

```
String myButtonText = getResources().getString(R.string.ButtonText);
```

Comment: No still doesnt run

Comment: Are you sure you have text in `strings.xml`.

Comment: 100% sure even the color of ButtonText changes

Comment: Put that thing inside `onCreate` method.